# Put a method in a different class to remove the switch() statement

Tags: php, oop

I will minimize the code down to just what you need to see.

I have 3 classes: `Customer`, `Courier` and `Order`.

```
class Customer extends AbstractRegisteredUser implements CustomerInterface {
}

class Courier extends AbstractRegisteredUser implements CourierInterface {
}

class Order extends AbstractEntity implements OrderInterface {

    private $customer;
    private $courier;

    public function isUserAssociated(RegisteredUserInterface $user) {

        switch( $user->GetEntityType() ) {
        case 'Customer':
            return $this->isCustomerAssociated($user);
        case 'Courier':
            return $this->isCourierAssociated($user);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function isCustomerAssociated(CustomerInterface $customer) {
        return ( $this->customer->getId() === $customer->getId() );
    }

    private function isCourierAssociated(CourierInterface $courier) {
        return ( $this->courier->getId() === $courier->getId() );
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a switch statement in there which I would prefer not to have so I have come up with doing it like this:

```
class Customer extends AbstractRegisteredUser implements CustomerInterface {
    public function isAssociatedWithOrder(OrderInterface $order) {
         return ( $this->getId() === $order->getCustomerId() );
    }
}

class Courier extends AbstractRegisteredUser implements CourierInterface {
    public function isAssociatedWithOrder(OrderInterface $order) {
         return ( $this->getId() === $order->getCourierId() );
    }
}
```

I can now remove the `isUserAssociated`, `isCustomerAssociated` and `isCourierAssociated` methods from the `Order` class and that ugly switch statement.

Now when I want to check if a customer is associated with a given order I do

```
// $user could be a customer or courier object.
if( !$user->isAssociatedWithOrder($order) ) {
}
```

Instead of

```
if( !$order->isUserAssociated($customer) ) {
}
```

It is a solution which requires less code, less methods and is easier on the eye but is it correct to do this? Should the `Customer` and `Courier` classes not know about the `Order`? Would this be considered giving a responsibility to a class which should not have that responsibility?

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asking for opinons on working code.  You may be able to get help on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you solution is valid, what happens when more user types come on board? It bogs down your order class with an ever increasing switch statement and methods.

It also increases the separation of concerns as a user being associated with an order is a concern for the user and not the order.